# How to define primary and foreign key in single hibernate mapping(hbm) file?

Tags: hibernate

I want to define a primary key and a foreign key in same hibernate mapping file (hbm) file. I am using hibernate 3.

I don't know how to specify both keys in generated class. The fields in my table are `id`, `eid` and `fname` where `id` holds the primary key, `eid` holds the foreign key and `fname` holds a string.

**assignleave.hbm.xml**:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="assignLeave" table="assignleave">
        <id name="id" column="id" type="integer">
            <generator class="assigned"></generator>
        </id>
        <id name="eid" column="eid" type="integer">
            <generator class="foreign"></generator>
        </id>
       <property name="fname" column="fname" type="string"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key is not an id column.

You have two mapping options :

- either you have en entity that represent the foreign table, in which case most you the time, you want to use a `many-to-one` mapping
- or this foreign table is not mapped by hibernate (or you do not wish to map the association with hibernate), in which case you map it with a simple `<property>` tag, and the `assignLeave` entity will have an integer field for the foreign key, something like `private Integer eid;`.